# Springboot RESTful API | what should i test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I'm creating restful api with springboot, hibernate crudRepository, spring security.
We plan to make :

- ui test in java&selenium,
- rest test Rest assured

Then what test should i make in backend? I'm plan to unit test but which? Services, controllers? Should use mockito to test service when mocking repository/dao or use datajpatest to memory db?

Comment: this question is too broad

Comment: Take a look at this: https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html
This will give you some idea of what you should test. Then you can ask another question on how to implement specific tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both should be tested:

- Integration test of controller using
  MockMvc(https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-boot-mockmvc-example/)
- Integration test of Service. Don't mock repository but use test db(h2). Mock only external services(for example client for payment connection).
- Unit test could be for some other service that used in your service.
  The main picture:Should be done end to end test integration test(main service that calls other services, controller) and during chain to the bottom of calls you could make unit tests